# Laravel - Update all column in the table with Join Statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to update all column in my fields for now i have the Join statement and im fetching the data but i cannot update all the columns

here is my join table name `movies` and i need to update all `aircraft_id` depending on what value i input

[image]

here is my Controller

```
  $getairId = DB::table('aircrafts')
  ->join('movies','movies.aircraft_id','=','aircrafts.aircraft_id')
  ->select('movies.*')
  ->update('aircraft_id.*')
  ->where('aircrafts.aircraft_id','=', $airid)
  ->get();
```

nothing is being updated.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

So assume that this is my page

[image]

and when i submit i should get this Actual Result / Output

[image]

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Please take a step back and include clear sample data for _both_ tables, and then show us what the expected result of the update should be.  Right now, I doubt anyone would even be able to guess here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hello sir , thank you for your advice please see my expected output/result i edited my question thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sir have you seen it?

Comment: Hi Summer, If you want to update the aircraft table only, then why you are making join on movies table?

Comment: I mean, is there any possible way to do it sir? i thought join will work dynamic and update all the column

Answer (score 1):

I assume that suppose you want to replace the aircraft id $airid = 1 with 3

```
$getairId = DB::table('aircrafts')
              ->join('movies','movies.aircraft_id','=','aircrafts.aircraft_id')
              ->where('aircrafts.aircraft_id','=', $airid)
              ->update(array("aircrafts.aircraft_id"=>3));
```

In the last update statement, you can pass your variable name which you want to update and come from your frontend form.

Hope,This code will work for you

Comment: hello ! it worked thanks, but last thing is let's assume that this is my textbox `$airid = $request->input('aircraft_id');` and i changed the update to `>update(array("series.aircraft_id"=>$airid));` why it did not work? it is not updating why? :(

Comment: After $airid = $request->input('aircraft_id');, What you are getting in $airid?

Comment: Try  $airid = $request->aircraft_id; directly